# How to draw a box around page title or get page title's size?

Tags: titles

I either need to draw a box around `\title` (to see how much space there is between the title, first line of text on the page [below the title], and top margin of the page [above the title]) or measure the `\title` in order to subtract appropriate `\vspace` from `\date` (to get rid of the big, unnecessary, space after the title so that the title will have same amount of space above and below---independent of top margin of the page).

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\date{}
\title{this is title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
this is line 1\\
this is line 2
\end{document}
```

[image]

ADDENDUM:
Getting size of the `\date` would also do.

Comment: You should take a look at the `titling` package which provides many tools to customise  `maketitle`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\date{}
\usepackage{framed}
\title
  { \begin{framed}
      this is (multiline) title\\
      let see how long this line extends before wrapping takes effect
    \end{framed}
  }
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  % don't know why but negating 3 times
  %  the \baselineskip works(?)
  %   (vertical spacing should be
  %    EXACTLY determined [from somewhere; any help?]
  %     before removal attempts)
  \vspace{\dimexpr(-\baselineskip*3)}
  \begin{framed}
    this is line 1\\
    this is line 2
  \end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Red lines are same size. Document border (5mm) is not considered by the title, or coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an `\fbox`.

```
\title{\fbox{this is title}}
```

However, if you have a multiline title then use `\parbox` instead like, perhaps (which unfortunately doesn't draw a box)

```
\title{\parbox{\textwidth}{this is a title too long to fit on one line}}
```

Leslie Lamport in his book *LaTeX: A Documentation Preparation System*, Addison-Wesly, 2nd edition, 1985, describes a `boxit` environment which will draw a box around multiline texts as (less any of my typos):

```
\newsavebox{\savepar}
\newenvironment{boxit}{\begin{lrbox}{\savepar}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}
{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\savepar}}}
```

which can be used for your title like this:

```
\title{\begin{boxit}this is a title but it is rather too long for a single line\end{boxit}}
```

For your purposes you may need to adjust the width and position of the `minipage` within the `boxit` definition.

Comment: @bp2017 I have extended my answer.

Comment: Have you tried using it on the title in my example? The title box becomes way wider than the title itself.

Comment: Note, \fbox adds precisely `2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule` to each dimension.